# Load Large JSON File in Django

Tags: python, json, django, loops, django-models

I try to open JSON File in local directory, the size of file is 250MB and have 1060000 data. I use for loop to save it to database. But, after done the total data that saved in database is not the same with data length. And this is my code.

```
json_data = open('dblama/4. inventaris_ruang.json')
data = json.load(json_data)

data_size = len(data)
print('length data:{}'.format(data_size))

for di in data:
   ivt = Inventaris()
   ivt.tahun = di['thn']
   ivt.nomor = di['nmr']
   ivt.barcode = di['rid']
   ivt.save()
```

And this is my model

```
class Inventaris(models.Model):
    tahun = models.CharField(max_length=4, null=True, blank=True)
    nomor = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)  
    barcode = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
```

Sometimes only 1052000 data that saved, sometimes 1056700 data. Why this is happen ?

Comment: Absolutely impossible to say without any code. What do you mean with "load large JSON file"? What do you mean with "open in django"? Use len on what? Use for loop and save what to database?

Comment: When you say, 1052000 data are saved, do you mean that `print('length data:{}'.format(data_size))` printed `"length data:1060000"`,but later you checked the DB and it only had 1052000?

Comment: We would need to know more about your model. Suppose you have a primary key but multiple items in your json file use that same key. Then some rows would update instead of creating new ones.

Comment: my model is like this, i havent change anything. And Yes it printed length data 106000 but later i check the DB is not the same.